# Reading strings from BufferReader

Tags: java

I'm trying to work on the html that i read with a BufferReader, like this:

```
try {
                HttpResponse response = DisplayMessageActivity.httpclient.execute(httppost);
                InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                String line="";
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                // Read response until the end
                char c = 'z';
                line = rd.readLine();
                c = line.charAt(0);
                switch(c){
                case 'a':
                    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                    String titolo = "";
                    final ArrayList<String> listaTitoli = new ArrayList<String>();
                    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
                        System.out.println(line);


                        if(line.startsWith("2")){
                            titolo = line.substring(2, (line.length()-4));
                            System.out.println(titolo);
                            listaTitoli.add(titolo);
                        }
                    }
                    if(!listaTitoli.isEmpty()){
                        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(URLHandlerActivity.this, R.layout.list_element, listaTitoli);
                        mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    break;
                }
                rd.close();

            }
```

The string "line" contains the html code like it should (i read that from the logcat), but the program never enters the "if(line.startsWith("2"))".
Having this happening i also tried to do this:

```
String str = "";
char c = 'z';
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
System.out.println(line);
str = line.substring(0);
System.out.println(str);
c = line.charAt(0);
System.out.println(c);
...
...
}
```

And in the logcat comes out that although "line" contains the html line, "str" and "c" are empty.

So how can i get the content of the string "line"?

Thank you for your help.

Edit:
The html i'm trying to read is like this (i can change it if necessary, it's my site):

```
a
-
1 8
0 ./immagini/Opera_img.jpg
2 Opera
3 Io
4 finto
5 1999-11-11
```

Comment: try trim the line first: `line = line.trim()` . I think you have spaces inside. Btw, can you post a small input for that function?

Comment: Thank you so much, i don't get that but seems it works.

Comment: You said that the line variable already contains the HTML line. That might mean that the line simply does not start with number 2. Rewrite your System.out.println(line) to System.out.println("|"+line+"|") to see what the line really contains.

Comment: @linski that wasn't the problem, also checked like you said. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @csoroiu if you write that as an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: @user2833876 added answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try trim the line first: line = line.trim().

I think you have spaces in front and after the actual text.

Answer (score 0):

In an unrelated note, this can be refactored as:

```
           case 'b':
                break;
            case 'c':
                break;
            case 'd':
                break;
            case 'e':
                break;
            }
            rd.close();
```

shown below:

```
    case 'b':                   
    case 'c':
    case 'd':
    case 'e':
    break;
 }
```